# Update row record with predefined value using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a specific record within a row with predefined valued using PHP and MySQL. I do not want to use "input" as my new value is defined in the code.

Table students

```
 id     name     grade   
 1      dave     b       Update< hyperlink to update.php
 2      mark     c       Update
 3      john     e       Update
 4      thomas   d       Update
```

Upon click on "Update" I want the grade value of specific row  to change to constant value"a", in every case. So lets say I clicked on Update within rows with id "1" and "2".

Desired result:

```
 id     name     grade   
 1      dave     a       Update
 2      mark     a       Update
 3      john     e       Update
 4      thomas   d       Update
```

I do know how to do it using input fields where I insert data myself and then submit. However I need to change the data upon click on Update.

This is how I display data:

```
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo ("<tr><td>$row[id]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[name]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[grade]</td>");
    echo ("<td><center><a href=\"udapte.php?id=$row[id]\">Update</a></center></td></tr>");
```

Update.php

```
// Connect to server and select databse.

$order = "UPDATE students 
      SET grade='a' 
      WHERE id='id'";
mysql_query($order);
```

I know mysql_* is not the safest way to do it. However once I get everything working I will modify php to use PDO.Thanks for help

Comment: You got some PHP lying around as well you want to share?

Comment: Nice, seems you got your answers below. Make sure you change your php to prevent sql injections though!

Comment: @span I've updated my answer using prepared statements. Rezus - you should highly consider using this method once you get it to work using what you already know.

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 1):

Pass the id of the record to be update by the href of the link.

1st, create those links with php in page.php. Rhose links call the same page, but with additional parameters within the url.
The code supposes all your records are stored in array $rows...

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {

    $h = $row['name'] . ', grade: ' . $row['grade'];
    $h.= ' <a href="page.php?do=update&id=' . $row['id'] . '">change grade</a>';
    echo $h . '<br />';

}
```

Then, in page.php quite at the beginning:

```
if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'update'] && isset($_GET['id])) {

  // enter your update code here
  // pls use mysqli_ or PDO instead of deprecated mysql_!

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the data directly after the update-click, you have to redirect back from update.php to the page using

```
header('location:currentpage.php');
```

or you can using Ajax.

if your code perfectly like what you've preovide above:

```
$order = "UPDATE students 
  SET grade='a' 
  WHERE id='id'";
 mysql_query($order);
```

the problem is you missed dollar sign ($) near your id variable. It should be

```
  ... id='$id'";
```

Comment: Yes I know about it and I have this included, however the update itself does not work.

Comment: what is 'does not work' means? error or what? please view my editted answer