# How can I update each row value in my table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with multiple rows. I want to update each row until I left the balance of my amount in first-in first-out (FIFO) order. Example table:

```
    id  value  balance
row  1   1000     1000
row  2   2000     2000
row  3   1500     1500
row  4   1000     1000
```

For this table I get 2500 (value to textbox `$topcfcacc`).

Now I want to pay the full value of the first row as it is smaller than the received amount. Then the second row and further, until my received amount remains 0.

```
$topcfcacc = $_POST['pcfc'];

$selectpcfc  = "SELECT * FROM `pcfc_disbursed` where status = 0 order by pcfc_disbursed_id asc";
$pcfc_result = mysqli_query($connection, $selectpcfc);
if (mysqli_num_rows($pcfc_result) > 0) 
{
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($pcfc_result);

    for ($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++) 
    {
       $pcfcrows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pcfc_result);
       $disbursed_id = $pcfcrows['pcfc_disbursed_id'];
       $disbursed   = $pcfcrows['disbursed_usd'];
       $usdbalance   = $pcfcrows['balance_usd'];
       $usdpaid      = $pcfcrows['paid_usd'];

       if($topcfcacc > $usdbalance)
       {
           $updatepcfc= "UPDATE `pcfc_disbursed` SET `balance_usd`=0,`paid_usd`=$usdbalance,`status`=1 WHERE pcfc_disbursed_id = $disbursed_id";
           $pcfc_update_result = mysqli_query($connection, $updatepcfc);
       }
       else
       {
           $updatepcfc= "UPDATE `pcfc_disbursed` SET 'balance_usd`=0,`paid_usd`=$usdbalance,`status`=1 WHERE pcfc_disbursed_id = $disbursed_id";
           $pcfc_update_result = mysqli_query($connection, $updatepcfc);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must do a better job of explaining the logic first before I look at the code.  What calculation do you use to go from the example table to 2500?  Then you want to do what?  More context please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update row record with predefined value using PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477517/update-row-record-with-predefined-value-using-php-and-mysql)